# Exporting single rows of a worksheet into .csv if the specific cell in column A of the row is NULL

Tags: vba, excel, csv

i m just challenging a task where the i want to export only specific rows of an Excel sheet into a .csv file.
The parameter would be that the full row is only selected for export if its cell in column A is not NULL/blank/not filled at all.

i managed to export whole worksheets but i cant find any hints on how to add this parameter. every promising thread i found was eventually about not exporting blank cells.

already tried to optimize the following code i found during my search so it fits my task but i miserably failed...
Help is much appreciated :-)

```
Sub ExportCSV()


Dim Bereich As Object, Zeile As Object, Zelle As Object
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strDateiname As String
Dim strTrennzeichen As String
Dim strMappenpfad As String
Dim blnAnfuehrungszeichen As Boolean

strMappenpfad = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

strDateiname = InputBox("Bitte den Namen der CSV-Datei angeben.", "CSV-Export", strMappenpfad)
If strDateiname = "" Then Exit Sub

strTrennzeichen = InputBox("Welches Trennzeichen soll verwendet werden?", "CSV-Export", ",")
If strTrennzeichen = "" Then Exit Sub

If MsgBox("Sollen die Werte in Anführungszeichen exportiert werden?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "CSV-Export") = vbYes Then
    blnAnfuehrungszeichen = True
Else
    blnAnfuehrungszeichen = False
End If

Set Bereich = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Open strDateiname For Output As #1

For Each Zeile In Bereich.Rows
    For Each Zelle In Zeile.Cells
        If blnAnfuehrungszeichen = True Then
            strTemp = strTemp & """" & CStr(Zelle.Text) & """" & strTrennzeichen
        Else
            strTemp = strTemp & CStr(Zelle.Text) & strTrennzeichen
        End If
    Next
    If Right(strTemp, 1) = strTrennzeichen Then strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
    Print #1, strTemp
    strTemp = ""
Next

  Close #1
  Set Bereich = Nothing
  MsgBox "Export erfolgreich. Datei wurde exportiert nach" & vbCrLf & strDateiname

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the first cell in each row is blank

```
For Each zeile In Bereich.Rows
    If Not zeile.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
        For Each Zelle In zeile.Cells
            If blnAnfuehrungszeichen = True Then
                strTemp = strTemp & """" & CStr(Zelle.Text) & """" & strTrennzeichen
            Else
                strTemp = strTemp & CStr(Zelle.Text) & strTrennzeichen
            End If
        Next
        If Right(strTemp, 1) = strTrennzeichen Then strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
        Print #1, strTemp
        strTemp = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you so much,  now i have the right idea how to make this work.